# PHP exec('program.exe') hangs webpage

Tags: php, windows, exec

As the title says, I can't get my PHP code to launch a program on the server via exec() at all.

A simple command like this works fine:

```
php.exe -r exec('mspaint.exe');
```

But if I try it from a webpage like this, it just hangs:

```
<?php
 if (isset($_POST['test'])) {

    exec('C:\Windows\System32\mspaint.exe 2>&1', $output);
    print_r($output);

}
?>

<html>
    <body>
        <form method="post">
        <input name="test" type="submit" value="test!" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I can only get errors or output on other commands like echo, but attempting to launch a .exe just hangs the webpage. I do notice the process for mspaint.exe shows up in the task manager, but the window itself never pops up.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The window pops up for the web server. The web server is not running as you. That is why we never do this.

Comment: No, the window does not pop up for the web server. I remote desktop into it, and no window pops up.

Comment: You remote as you, not the web server.

Comment: I have a feeling it has to do with permissions on Windows. I followed every step mentioned [here](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#86438), which was to give cmd.exe permissions, allowed the lighttpd service to interact with the desktop, and used psexec, but the page still hangs!

Comment: That's because you aren't supposed to do that.  The lighthttpd server is running as a system service, and processes started by system services are non-interactive, i.e., you can't see them.  This is by design, it is what is supposed to happen.  Note that the "interact with the desktop" option was deprecated starting with Windows Vista / Server 2008, and no longer works unless you also enable the "Interactive Services Detection" service (which is for backwards compatibility).

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem though.  What are you actually trying to achieve?  Why do you want to launch a GUI process via a webpage?

Comment: I'm actually trying to launch an AutoHotKey script I made that restarts my Battlefront II server on GameRanger. It clicks all the necessary buttons and whatnot. I wanted it available on a webpage so (trusted) players can reboot it via a password when I'm not around.

Comment: I stand corrected; that sounds like a legitimate (if somewhat obscure!) use case.  It is possible for a service that runs as local system to launch a program in the interactive user's context, but that would be a bit tricky.  Perhaps you could leave a batch file running that checks for the existence of a file every few seconds and if found, sets off your script?  Then the PHP code could just create the file.

Comment: Note, however, that if the logged-on session running Battlefront II isn't visible on the physical or remote display - if the session is locked, or if you've used "switch user" - the AutoHotKey script might not work.  I've never quite grasped why, but GUI automation doesn't always behave as expected when the session isn't visible.

Comment: I kind of have a bit of experience with remote desktop + AHK, and I learned that Send doesn't work when the GUI isn't visible but ControlSend does. Lots of debugging to figure that out. Anyway, having PHP create a file should be easier than launching a program? I might try it then somehow. I just find it amazing that something as simple as launching a GUI program is so difficult. I guess for security reasons then huh?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99153/discussion-between-ryza-jr-and-harry-johnston).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code :

system("*:/***.exe");

$result=passthru('dir');
print $result;

Further reading open http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php

Comment: I am not sure it's working or not, because i have not implemented this.

Comment: That may work for a command-line process, but the OP is trying to run a GUI process.